# student research project ideas

Tags: discussion, advice

Is it possible to ask about student research project ideas in this website?

Comment: **OH MY GOD. CAPITAL LETTERS!** Twist and *SHOUT*!

Comment: Dear Rahman, Are you a student wanting to do a project (which is what the answers below seem to assume) or a teacher/professor wanting to give a project to a student?  Regards,

Comment: I am a student looking or help in finding subject for my master thesis

Comment: @Rahman Then definitely my answer fits.  If you want to work on a masters thesis, you talk with your adviser and they help you find a suitable problem.

Comment: Do you have an adviser?

Comment: yes actually .. if one can ask experts here about the subject of the project in general.. not necessary to give you an exact problem

Answer (score 11):

In the past, I have seen several such requests and one answer that always shows up and is usually the most popular is:

This is not the right place to ask this.  It would be better to ask your teacher/adviser who will be helping you and who knows you better.

Comment: Exactly this. It depends so much on your personal situation that there can be no specific answer given on what you should choose, only advice on how you can make the choice. If it's this kind general of advice that you're looking for, then the this seems like an acceptable question to ask; from the FAQ this seems like a  "practical, answerable question(s) based on actual problems that you face". On the other hand, as pointed out above, this type of question has been asked (and answered) before, so perhaps just searching for previous questions would be enough to answer yours.

Answer (score 7):

On top of what Graphth says, and I agree with, if you are looking for projects which might lead to publishable original work and can be worked on by an undergraduate in the course of a few months, it is really hard to find such questions. I have a very small number saved up for the REU program at Michigan this summer, and I don't want to give them away. I suspect that most mathematicians who mentor undergraduate research feel the same way.

Comment: I read the question differently, as in "I have thought of the following projects ... but I am unsure of their feasibility, and would appreciate comments in this regard from people with more experience." Regardless of whether this was the OP's intention, would you find such a question appropriate for the site?

Comment: @AndresCaicedo: I do not know about appropriate, but if they were wanting to publish the results then they wouldn't want to do that! (Unless it is a well-known open problem, and then the answer would be `you're probably out of your depth'...)